# The showErrors() function of jQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

The following script works fine:

```
$("#regform").validate().showErrors({"username":"message"});
```

After I changed the script to the below one, it doesn't work.

```
var name = "username";
$("#regform").validate().showErrors({name:"message"});
```

I need to pass the field name by a variable. Anyone knows how this problem can be solved?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should build an object literal and use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) member access operator:

```
var name = "username",
    obj = {};
obj[name] = "message";

$("#regform").validate().showErrors(obj);
```